# While-loop in UILongPressGestureRecognizer not working

Tags: ios, swift, while-loop, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to adjust the position of my textField as I long-press my view, but for some reason the while-loop never stops running. My code looks like this:

```
func buttonLongPressed(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){
    if textEdit.editing == true{
    self.textEdit.endEditing(true)
    }
    while gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began{
    println("BEGAN")
    self.textEdit.frame = CGRectMake(0, gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.view).y, self.view.frame.width, 44)

    }
}
```

I don't understand why this shouldn't work, and how to do it in any other way.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gesture recognizer calls your action method when its state changes--it's not valid to poll the state from a while loop, it will never change.

It probably works like this:

- Events are sent from the touch screen with a signal to wake up your app.
- The gesture recognizer looks at the queued events and decides to enter "Began" state.
- The gesture recognizer code invokes your action method (buttonLongPressed)
  Your code enters a while look and reads *gestureRecognizer.state* repeatedly.

You can see, if your action method never returns, the gesture recognizer will never wake up again and look at new input.

You can probably just change your function like this:

```
func longPressAction( g:UILongPressGestureRecognizer )
{
    switch g.state
    {
        case: .Changed
        {
            // handle one drag update... but don't loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so it's impossible to somehow track the position of my movement in the view?

Comment: No, you just have to track it over multiple calls. Handle one move, return, handle the next move, etc.

Comment: Okay. Do you have any other suggestions on how to make the text field follow my touch?